# r - loop through all classification models in "caret" package

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I am trying to find the three models with highest Area Under Curve value by going through every classification model in the "caret" package for ensemble learning.

```
myControl <- trainControl(method='cv', number=3, returnResamp='none')
# getting the list of "classification" models
is_class <- unlist(lapply(getModelInfo(), function(x) any(x$type == "Classification")))
class_mods <- names(is_class)[is_class]


for (i in 1:length(class_mods))
{

  model_ <- train(ensembleData[,predictors], ensembleData[,labelName], method=class_mods[i], trControl=myControl)
  preds <- predict(object=model_, testingData[,predictors])
  auc <- roc(testingData[,labelName],as.numeric(preds))
  x=c(auc$auc,class=mods[i])    
  write.table(x, "results1.csv", append=TRUE)
}
```

I am getting this error: "`Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing`"

A better way of doing this problem is also welcome.

ensembleData and testingData contains 666 rows of observations, each with 5000 features, and the last column consists of the classification of the observation: 1 or 0.

Comment: there are a few hundred methods, I think it is quite optimistic for you to get this to work in a few lines of code. maybe wrap your expressions in a `tryCatch` and go from there although you will be prompted to download probably a few hundred packages

Comment: @rawr You are absolutely right. I have been prompted to download packages. Going with your suggestion, since I am not very familiar with trycatch() (I will youtube it), how will trycatch() help in this situation? For example, will it provide more detailed error message? Thanks.

Comment: this error message is the same when you have NAs in the data